# How to fetch events from database with a time data type in FullCalendar v4

Tags: php, xampp, fullcalendar

I'm new to web programming and I'm trying to fetch the time and day from my database and display them on my *fullcalendar*.

How would I get the value with ***time*** data type to show on my calendar and how would I add a daysOfWeek to it.

I have this code that works for fetching the events with ***datetime*** data type but I need another one for static events that occur every week from the database.

fetchevents.php

```php
<?php
    require_once "dbconn.php";

    $json = array();
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events ORDER BY id";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
    $eventArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($eventArray, $row);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($eventArray);
?>
```

This is some code I tried, the array is wrong but here's what I did

fetchevents.php

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
    $eventArray = array(
        'title' => $row['section_name'],
        'startTime' => $row['time_start'],
        'endTime' => $row['time_end'],
        'daysOfWeek' => $row['day_id'] 
    );
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($eventArray, $row);
    }
```

then I called it on my *eventSources*

```js
eventSources:[
        {
        url: "../include/fetchevents.php"
        }
    ],
```

#### This code produces the output I expect but I can't figure out how to get the values from my database and assign them.

```js
events:[
        {
        title: 'Exams', // get title from db
        startTime: '10:00', // get start time from db
        endTime: '13:00', // get end time from db
        daysOfWeek: ['1','3'] // get daysID from db
        }
    ]
```

[Here is a sample picture of my desired output for the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAOBn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate the event array inside the  while loop, like so:

```
$eventArray = array(); // Initialize empty array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Push to the eventArray one array for each row
    $eventArray[] = array(
        'title' => $row['section_name'],
        'startTime' => $row['time_start'],
        'endTime' => $row['time_end'],
        'daysOfWeek' => $row['day_id'] 
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to join the *title* as 'title' => $row['section_name']." - Rm ".$row['room_number']

So that it will show something like "Math - Rm 502"

Comment: Yeah, that should work. `'title' => "$row['section_name'] - Rm $row['room_number']"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :D